# In WIN XP how to set default FTP application to be Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, ftp

How I can tell my Win XP to again opening FTP folders trough normal explorer.
Since Internet Explorer 7 my windows do not opening links of ftp sites trough normal file windows explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 says this when I open a FTP site:

> To view this FTP site in Windows Explorer, click **Page**, and then click **Open FTP Site in Windows Explorer**.

If the `Open FTP site in Windows` option is not available then make sure that the `Enable FTP Folder View (outside of Internet Explorer)` option is checked in the advanced options (`Tools`->`Internet Options`->`Advanced`).

**Update:**

Found a blog post by *The IE Support Team* on [how to force Windows Explorer to be the default handler for FTP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askie/ftp-and-internet-explorer-what-to-do-what-to-do). You must edit the registry:

> **BEFORE (32bit)**
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.FTP\shell\open\command]
>
> @=""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.FTP\shell\open\ddeexec\Application]
>
> @="IExplore"
>
> **AFTER (32bit)**
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.FTP\shell\open\command]
>
> @="C:\Windows\explorer.exe %1"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.FTP\shell\open\ddeexec\Application]
>
> @="Explorer"

Answer (score 1):

You can [Create a shortcut to (map) a network drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive) in Explorer via the menu entry File / Add a network location.

If user and password are required, use the syntax of :

> `ftp://user:password@ftpserver/url-path`